# add column SELECT filter in grid menu

Tags: gridview, select, magento, filter

I’m trying to add select in my column “Sources” to allow filter, all this code works well, but I’m trying to add filter without any success, anyone can point me in the right direction?

Until know I have:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('source', 'customer/source', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

and

```
$this->addColumn('source', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Source'),
        'type'      => 'source',
        'index'     => 'source'
    ));
```

Any help will be very apreciated
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found the solution for transform in
>   a **Select** option:

```
$sql = 'SELECT distinct value FROM `....';
$data = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource') ->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($sql);

$soTypes=array();
foreach($data as $array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(!empty($value)){
      $so[$value]=$value;
    }
  }
}

$this->addColumn('invoice_so', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SoTypes'),
    'index'     => 'value',
    'width'     => '100px',
    'type'      => 'options',
    'options' => $soTypes,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

The type value should not be `source`. That doesn't do anything. It needs to be one of the classes in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/`.

> - Checkbox
> - Country
> - Date
> - Datetime
> - Massaction
> - Price
> - Radio
> - Range
> - Select
> - Store
> - Text
> - Theme